# Realm managing subobjects

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

can you help me out?

For my current context in an app I'm trying to manage a - parsed from json - object through multiple Realms. Due to my requirements I'm bound to use a Realm for my raw converted POJOs, a Realm for an app-session instance and a Realm for a subobject related session (since I'm managing Object copies per session).

The question: How do I properly manage (managed or unmanaged) RealmObjects while copying them from one Realm to another?

Heres my current code:

```
Realm.getInstance(RealmManager.sessionsConfig)?.also{ sessionsRealm -> 
    try{
    sessionsRealm.executeTransaction{ 
        // Make a clean setup 
        realm.deleteAll() 
        val copyRootObject = sessionsRealm.copyToRealm(originalRootObject)

        // Ignore flat hierarchy if only one place with one campaign is provided 
        if(copyRootObject.place?.children?.size!! == 0){ 
                copyRootObject.campaign?.apply { 
                    parameters = copyRootObject.parameters 
                    dynamicfields = copyRootObject.dynamic_fields 
                    survey_topics = copyRootObject.survey_topics 
                } 
                copyRootObject.apply { 
                    place?.campaigns = RealmList() 
                    place?.campaigns?.add(copyRootObject.campaign) 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }catch(e: Exception){ 
        e.printStackTrace()
    }finally { 
        realm.close() 
        openStartFragment() 
    } 
}
```

During the process of opening my main activity which displays the POJOs contents I'm trying to copy the original whole RealmObject from my raw Realm to my "instances" Realm. While this is happening I'm also trying to move some subobjects in my copied objects into a different field because the REST API I'm using is a bit broken.
Problem is though, the shown code doesn't seem to work. While I'm able to find the copied object, the reassigned subobjects are not being moved to the specified fields.
Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why not have two separate classes for API response and database classes?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I dont really understand your question. The API I'm using provides a JSON that I use for further display, which is parsed to RealmObjects and then inserted into a Realm